# PySpark: java.sql.SQLException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to read a table from a MySQL database and then uploading the data into a Redshift from Amazon AWS.
The problem is that when I try to write the rows into the RedShift, I'm getting the error:

`java.sql.SQLException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1`

The data coming from the MySQL database is on UTC.
I tried to set the parameter serverTimezone=UTC on the string connection and it solves the problem, however when I query the data on redshift after writing it, my dates are with a 3h difference from the original date on MySQL.

When I run the command `SHOW timezone` on redshift, I get `America/Sao Paulo`.

I tried to change the timezone from my redshift user using the command `ALTER USER myuser SET TIMEZONE TO default` as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_timezone_config.html. But when I run the command SHOW TIMEZONE I still get `America/Sao Paulo`.

I cannot really understand where the error is and how to solve it, could you guys please help me?